# CSS unhover property

Tags: html, css, button, css-animations

Im trying to animate a round border, that becomes square when you hover, and goes back to a circle after you unhover. Despite my best efforts, i can't seem to make it work. Here is what i have so far.

```css
@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    border-radius: 100% 100%;
  }
  to {
    border-radius: 0px, 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes mymoveback {
  from {
    border-radius: 0px 0px;
  }
  to {
    border-radius: 100%, 100%;
  }
}

.testButt {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 3s;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation: mymoveback 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.testButt:hover {
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation: mymove 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<div class="testButt">
  <br><br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Log In
</div>
```

Comment: Where’s your HTML? What isn’t working?

Comment: The html isn't much, just a div conatining this, if you want i can provide it.

Comment: why animation ? use simple transiation

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You over complicate it, simply use [transition](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) like this:

```css
.testButt {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding:40px 0;
  text-align:center;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.testButt:hover {
  border-radius: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="testButt">
  Log In
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

HTML:

```
<button>Hover Me!</button>
```

And CSS:

```
button {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000)
}

button:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

And link to fiddle:
[Hover and round animation](https://jsfiddle.net/e57yr8Lt/7/)

Comment: pay attention as transition-duration should be use with a unit [s or ms] and in this case it's useless because you will override it with transition later ... and there is no need to add the border property on hover

Comment: Could you please explain what cubic-beizer is?

Comment: Please find below definition from w3schools:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_cubic-bezier.asp
And here is tool to play it:
http://cubic-bezier.com